# Generating all combinations with unknown length

Tags: c++, cartesian-product

I'm practicing in programming and I generating all combinations in c++. I know how to generate all combination in 
certain length 
My result is something like that

```
A A A
A A B
A A C
A B A
A B B
A B C
A C A
A C B
A C C
B A A
.....
```

and my problem is, I don't know, how to generate all combinations with unknown length. For example I want word length = 5 and program will generate all combination in exactly length 5. How to do it?

```
A A A A A
A A A A B
A A A A C
A A A B A
.........
```

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Can we use C++ to answer your question? EDIT: Sorry, didn't see for loop initializers.

Comment: This type of problem is easier to solve using recursion instead of iteration. Once you've solved the recursive algorithm, turn it into an iterative algorithm again.

Comment: "practicing in programming and I generating all combinations in c++" --> Then why tag `C`?  Recommend edit to tag with one language.  A good  answer may depend on the language.

Comment: @IInspectable , sorry, I don't know, how exactly to do it. Please, can you write some pseudocode?

Answer (score 1):

See the link [Print all permutations with repetition of characters](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-permutations-with-repetition-of-characters/)

The below recursive function in the page, can create last+1 length permutations.

```
/* The main function that recursively prints all repeated 
permutations of  the given string. It uses data[] to store all
permutations one by one */
void allLexicographicRecur (char *str, char* data, int last, int index)
{
  int i, len = strlen(str);

  // One by one fix all characters at the given index and recur for 
  // the/ subsequent indexes
  for ( i=0; i<len; i++ )
  {
      // Fix the ith character at index and if this is not the last 
      // index then recursively call for higher indexes
      data[index] = str[i] ;

     // If this is the last index then print the string stored in
     // data[]
     if (index == last)
         printf("%s\n", data);
     else // Recur for higher indexes
        allLexicographicRecur (str, data, last, index+1);
  }
}
```

I think this can serve your purpose. 
Call **allLexicographicRecur** with the required (length-1) value for the 'last' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually nothing more than **counting**.

If you have the letters A, B, and C, you are counting in base 3.
A is 0, B is 1 and C is 2.

Quick and dirty:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const int base = 3;
        const char zero_char = 'A';
        const size_t length = 5;
        std::string out;
        for(int n = i; n > 0; ) {
            int d = n%base;
            out = static_cast<char>(zero_char + d) + out;
            n /= base;
        }
        while(out.length() < length) out = zero_char + out;
        std::cout << out << '\n';
    }
}
```

[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4845f7dd78ab7df6)

---

The possible combinations are *base<sup>length</sup>*, so if you want all combinations for A, B, C with 5 digits, change the limit of the first `for` loop to 3<sup>5</sup> ( = 243):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 243; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
bool increase(const std::string& s, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] >= s.size()) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void do_job(const std::string& s,
            const std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != it.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << s[it[i]] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void cartesian_product(const std::string& s, std::size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(n, 0u);

    do {
        do_job(s, it);
    } while (increase(s, it));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Zqx5B9)